# Ping timeout on tracert second node

Tags: timeout, ping, router, lag, latency

I have been having occasional lag spikes while playing online realtime games (LoL for example). I ran a `tracert` to LoL's servers (216.52.241.254):

```
C:\Windows\system32>tracert -d 216.52.241.254

Tracing route to 216.52.241.254 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.0.1
  2    29 ms    29 ms    26 ms  68.84.4.1
  3    10 ms     8 ms    10 ms  68.85.80.165
  4     9 ms    11 ms    70 ms  68.85.130.85
  5    14 ms    15 ms    15 ms  68.86.90.85
  6    12 ms    12 ms    11 ms  68.86.82.222
  7    13 ms    13 ms    12 ms  66.208.229.142
  8    48 ms    13 ms    13 ms  154.54.6.170
  9    26 ms    25 ms    26 ms  154.54.31.97
 10    44 ms    45 ms    46 ms  154.54.29.222
 11    75 ms    74 ms    73 ms  154.54.7.158
 12    76 ms    75 ms    75 ms  154.54.47.170
 13    76 ms    76 ms    75 ms  154.24.22.122
 14    77 ms    74 ms    74 ms  38.104.77.122
 15    74 ms    74 ms    75 ms  216.52.241.254

Trace complete.
```

and did a `ping -t` to the first few nodes to see if the problem showed up there. I let that run while I was playing, and checked on it whenever I had a lag spike or disconnect. The results for the first two nodes:

Localhost:

```
C:\Windows\system32>ping -t 192.168.0.1

Pinging 192.168.0.1 with 32 bytes of data:

...omitted...

Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 192.168.0.1:
    Packets: Sent = 2, Received = 2, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 1ms, Maximum = 1ms, Average = 1ms
Control-C
^C
```

Second node:

```
C:\Windows\system32>ping -t 68.84.4.1

Pinging 68.84.4.1 with 32 bytes of data:

...omitted...

Reply from 68.84.4.1: bytes=32 time=8ms TTL=254
Reply from 68.84.4.1: bytes=32 time=14ms TTL=254
Reply from 68.84.4.1: bytes=32 time=12ms TTL=254
Reply from 68.84.4.1: bytes=32 time=10ms TTL=254
Reply from 68.84.4.1: bytes=32 time=15ms TTL=254
Reply from 68.84.4.1: bytes=32 time=10ms TTL=254
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Reply from 68.84.4.1: bytes=32 time=11ms TTL=254
Reply from 68.84.4.1: bytes=32 time=11ms TTL=254
Reply from 68.84.4.1: bytes=32 time=10ms TTL=254
Reply from 68.84.4.1: bytes=32 time=8ms TTL=254
Reply from 68.84.4.1: bytes=32 time=10ms TTL=254
Reply from 68.84.4.1: bytes=32 time=9ms TTL=254
Reply from 68.84.4.1: bytes=32 time=14ms TTL=254
Reply from 68.84.4.1: bytes=32 time=10ms TTL=254
Reply from 68.84.4.1: bytes=32 time=15ms TTL=254
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 68.84.4.1:
    Packets: Sent = 2911, Received = 2889, Lost = 22 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 4ms, Maximum = 2953ms, Average = 12ms
Control-C
^C
```

Each line of the results should roughly match the corresponding line in the other in terms of time of ping. Sometimes, I have multiple timeouts like above, while other times, it is only one or two lines with very high latency (>900ms). I also had results for a few more nodes, but those had the same behavior, so I figured the problem was in the second node.

I recently got a new router because Comcast cut off our internet, saying, "You have to upgrade your router. It's outdated and you're not taking advantage of the speedups we've been implementing in your area." I cannot recall if we had this lag spike problem before we got the new router because I spent most of my time at school.

My question is: Is this a problem with my router or with the house's connection to the rest of the internet?

---

EDIT:
The problem seems to arise only when I am playing. I have been running a `ping -t` to 68.84.4.1 for the last hour while not playing, and have not seen it timeout a single time. The results are:

```
Ping statistics for 68.84.4.1:
    Packets: Sent = 3477, Received = 3476, Lost = 1 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 5ms, Maximum = 88ms, Average = 10ms
```

Over the entire hour, the max latency was 88ms, and only 1 packet was lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be a number of reasons that cause games to lag on a machine besides the internet connection.
Assuming that the problem lies in your connection

*The first point is most relevant to your question, rest are just suggestions*

1. **Perform a "full" Speedtest:** the data you provided only tells half of the story, do a proper speed test using some online service like [Speedtest.net by Ookla](http://www.speedtest.net/). Network games have high bandwidth requirements so take a note of the (total) bandwidth that comes to your home. If no other devices and/or program is consuming your network bandwith, you shall have a similar value. you may also do a DNS speed test using [Namebench](https://code.google.com/p/namebench/)
2. **Use a Wired Connection:** A wireless connection will always add latency to bandwidth. Disconnect from the router and use a wired connection directly to the computer. Also, if others are using the router at the same time, it is possible that there are too many people grabbing for the same bandwidth.
   However **if that is not possible make sure that the router is properly configured**. It must be in the right position, at the right elevation, wireless channel etc for optimal performance.
   There are number of [guides available online](http://lifehacker.com/5931743/top-10-ways-to-boost-your-home-wi-fi) which you can follow.
   Also look out for any new wireless networks in your area that may interfere with your signal.
   **Try a different router firmware,** as some routers have broken firmware and don't perform well on excess load , give **Gargoyle** or **OpenWRT** a chance if you are desperate.
3. **Close down other applications that use the internet**
4. **Optimize your game settings:** All popular online games have network settings, its just a case of finding them. Search online for a guide to tweaking your game.
5. **Turn on Compound TCP**, which increases the TCP window much quicker than the traditional TCP algorithms allow for. This means that when a sudden burst of larger packets comes in, or goes out, Windows adjusts its settings faster than normal to compensate for it, allow for faster data transfer on broadband connections and lower latency while gaming.

   netsh int tcp set global congestionprovider=ctcp
6. **Enable UPnP on your router:** This will automatically route the correct data to the correct ports.
7. **Experiment at different days and time for lags**
8. **Try a Speed optimizer like** [SG TCP Optimizer](http://www.speedguide.net/downloads.php)
9. Lastly make sure that you have the latest Drivers installed and are
   using compatible hardware.

Comment: 1. Here's my speedtest.net results: [link](http://www.speedtest.net/my-result/3570151062). I'm fairly certain 50mbps down and 8mbps up should be able to handle most games' bandwidth needs. The problem is the occasional latency spikes.

Comment: 2. I'll try this when I get an ethernet cable, but from the `ping` tests, it looks like I can connect to 192.168.0.1 just fine.

3. No other applications were open at the time.

7. It does seem like some times of the day, it's worse that other times but I haven't noticed a pattern.

9. Drivers are up to date, according to my computer's manufacturer's drivers page.

Comment: Also, for 5., how come Compound TCP isn't enabled by default?

Comment: It is but on beta versions of Windows Server. I am pretty sure that it is disabled on other machines, you can wiki Compound TCP to see which OS versions have it enabled by default.

Comment: You mentioned that the router is new, is it properly configured? when I got my first router I spend hours optimizing it's settings. I even installed a custom firmware which worked well for me.

Comment: Hm, no, I haven't configured it at all. I wasn't the one who set it up since I wasn't at home. How do I know what are good values for optimization? Just Google it?

Comment: yes, that should work, and some common sense! :-)
if in doubt, feel free to ask.

Comment: Haha, I will. In the meantime, I'll go try those tweaks and optimizations. Thanks!

Comment: Google each individual setting names for best results. All the Best!

Comment: Sorry, I realized I didn't accept this answer. BTW, I found out that the reason for the lag spikes was because once in a while (for reasons that I am not sure of), the connection to the router becomes very slow. Speedtest over Ethernet cable is always consistent. **The fix that worked for me was to simply make any configuration change to the 802.11 radio settings (e.g. 20Hz -> 40Hz or change the channel)**. My router is the **Arris Surfboard SBG6580**.

Comment: Nice to hear that. Note that many routers are set to automatically use channel 1 by default so if you have neighbors, it might have been the reason for the lag spikes. Also note that 20Hz propagates better through obstacles as compared to 40Hz even though the later offers more bandwidth.

Comment: I'll do some more testing on the radio settings, but it seems to me that the actual configuration doesn't matter. If I change it to 40Hz and then back to 20Hz, the problem goes away. It's like I need to "wake up" the router every so often.